# How to separate a complex number into standard a + bi form?

Tags: complex-numbers

How might we separate

$$
\psi  =(2/\pi)^{1/4} {1\over\sqrt{1+2it}}~\Large e^{-\frac{(x-2t)^2}{1+4t^2} } e^{ 2i\frac{x-t+tx^2}{1+4t^2}} .
$$

into the standard a + bi form of a complex number, where a and b are trigonometric cos and sin functions?

Comment: i could not separate the coefficient sqrt(1+2it) because of the square root

Comment: It is beneficial to use $a + b \, i = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \, e^{i \, \tan^{-1}(b/a)}$ which leads to $\sqrt{1 + 2 \, i \, t} = \sqrt[4]{1+4 \, t^2} \, e^{i/2\, \tan^{-1}(2 t)}$ which gives the general form $$ \psi = \left(\frac{2}{\pi \, (1+4 t^2)} \right)^{1/4} \, e^{- f(x,t)} \, e^{i (2 g(x,t) - 1/2 \, \tan^{-1}(2 t))}$$ which can then lead to a $\cos$ and $\sin$ form.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint (I don't have enough rep to comment), try rewriting $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2it}}$ as $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\text{log}(1+2it)}$ and use some of the properties of the complex logarithm.

Comment: thank you. I have tried and the i is now inside the expanded trigonometric functions, how can we evaluate cos(log(1+2it))?

Comment: Back up a few steps... try rewriting $\log(1+2it)$ first before expanding into trig functions. Note that any complex number can be written in the form $z = re^{i\theta}$ so that $\log(z) = \log(re^{i\theta}) = \log(r) + i\theta$