# How to integrate $\int \frac{e^{-ikt}}{\sqrt{1+it}}\,dt$ numerically?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, numerical-methods

How should one numerically integrate a complex exponential function like

$$\int \frac{e^{-ikt}}{\sqrt{1+it}} dt$$

where it is not obvious how to separate the real and imaginary parts of integrand?

Using Euler's formula:

$$ \sum \frac{\cos (kt) - i \sin (kt)}{\sqrt{1+it}} \Delta t$$

seems to require us, first of all, to be able to **separate** [(eg. this integral)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695119/how-to-numerically-integrate-int-infty-infty-frace-ikt1t2-dt/4695192#4695192) the real and imaginary parts cleanly before applying numerical integration?

Comment: Numerically integrate over what domain?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is just a constant, then remove the denominator: the integral is $1/(1+i\lambda)\int e^{-ikt}\,dt$.  You know how to integrate $e^{-ikt}$ with respect to $t$, yes?

Comment: Removed my comment, @KCd noticed what I missed. I inferred a $t$ downstairs that simply isn’t there. 

Comment: @Aruralreader is there a theorem that all complex number forms can in principle be separated into $a + ib$?

Comment: It's not a theorem, that is quite literally the **definition** of a complex number

Comment: @K.defaoite i seem to recall having come across in the past some numbers where it does not seem possible to do this, eg. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594471/how-to-separate-a-complex-number-into-standard-a-bi-form

Comment: i updated the question with a harder denominator so someone can answer in specific.

Comment: In general, for a function $\int g(t)\,dt$, one can numerically evaluate $g(t)$ (for reasonably well-behaved $g$), then split into real and complex parts, and integrate each part separately before adding. For the example you linked to, it might be tricky to explicitly reduce that into $a+bi$ form, but since you're numerically integrating, you could just find $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2it}}$ and $e^{2i\frac{x-t+tx^2}{1+4t^2}-\frac{(x-2t)^2}{1+4t^2}}$ and multiply them.

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{e^{-i k t}}{\sqrt{1+i t}}\, dt$$
then you can make the substitution $t=-i s$ (so $dt=-i\, ds$ and $s=i t$) and evaluate
$$-i\int \frac{e^{-k s}}{\sqrt{1+s}}\, ds$$
and then substitute $s=i t$ into the result to get back to a function of $t$. If you're trying to evaluate a definite integral then you need to specify the evaluation limits which could be real or complex.

Comment: @Kyky thank you. yes, the point-wise evaluation into $a+ib$ form before summing each $a+ib$ element explicitly should work for nearly any complicated function!

Comment: @StevenClark. Your hint is really the best way to use (we even have the explicit solution for checking the result. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\sqrt{1+it}=a+ib$$

where $a=a(t), b=b(t)$ are real functions.

Square it, we get
$$1+it=a^2-b^2+2abi$$

Compare the real and imaginary part, we get

$$1=a^2-b^2,~~~t=2ab$$

Solve and we get

$$a=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}},~~b=\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}}$$

$$$$
Therefore,

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+it}}&=\frac{1}{a+ib}=\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}}\end{align}$$

Further,

$$\begin{align}\frac{e^{-ikt}}{\sqrt{1+it}}&=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}-i\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}\right)(\cos kt-i\sin kt)\\
\\
&=R(t)+i\cdot I(t)\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{align}R(t)&=\cos kt\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}-\sin kt\cdot\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}\\
\\
I(t)&=-\cos kt\cdot\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}-\sin kt
\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2(1+t^2)}}\end{align}$$

Hence, your integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{e^{-ikt}}{\sqrt{1+it}} dt=\int R(t) dt+i\int I(t) dt$$

Now you can do the numerical integration on these two real integrals.

Comment: For complex numbers $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} \neq \sqrt{ab}$ so that throws your premise off.

Comment: $a,b$ are real functions @NinadMunshi

Comment: You misunderstand, I mean your first step where you claim $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+it}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-it}}{\sqrt{1-it}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-it}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$ (which actually reveals a second mistake in your first line). We cannot claim that equality because of the lack of that property of being able to combine products of square roots.

Comment: You can treat them as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-it}}=\frac{1}{a+ib}=\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}$$, so it can save some typing work. @NinadMunshi

Comment: That is a good idea! Then do that instead of what you have written and fix the mistakes.

Comment: Actually on my draft paper, I did in this way, but when I typed in, I thought this is kind of redundant, so I choose a lazy way, but to be rigorous I should type it in this way as you suggested. Thank you! @NinadMunshi

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, I remember answered you another numerical integral question a few hours ago :) @James

Comment: Your substitution for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+i t}}$ is not valid for $t<0$. The real part, which is an even function of $t$, matches but not the imaginary part. The imaginary part of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+i t}}$ is an odd function of $t$ whereas the imaginary part of your substitution is an even function of $t$ (see [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BIm%5B1%2FSqrt%5B1%2BI+t%5D%5D%2CIm%5B1%2FSqrt%5B1%2Bt%5E2%5D+Sqrt%5B%281%2BSqrt%5B1%2Bt%5E2%5D%29%2F2%5D+-I+1%2FSqrt%5B1%2Bt%5E2%5D+Sqrt%5B%28-1%2BSqrt%5B1%2Bt%5E2%5D%29%2F2%5D%5D%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D)).

Comment: $$1=a^2-b^2,~~~t=2ab$$
Yes, because if $t<0$, we need to put a minus sign for $a$ or $b$ after taking the square root to get the following expression. 
$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}},~~b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}}$$ Which sign to choose depends on the specific case in the author's application. Since we are not given on what interval the OP will do the integration, I only give the result for one case $a>0, b>0$, and it is not difficult to modify this result for other signs in the application. @StevenClark